# How is the fundamental frequency of a large rotating body determined?

Tags: vibration

Okay, I understand that "large" is relative. I'm referring to the 60" diameter 5000 rpm counterrotating flywheels I've postulated in [this question](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/235448/support-equipment-for-a-time-machine). When I was taking flying lessons in an 8KCAB Decathlon there was an RPM band (2000-2250 rpm) which we were told to avoid due to vibration resonance. It occurs to me that there should be a similar critical frequency band for my time travelers which they should either avoid or otherwise try to pass through as expeditiously as possible. Is this determined experimentally, or is there a way to craft a decent estimate of it given the postulated design parameters?

Comment: It's not just the flywheel. It's everything the flywheel is connected to.

Comment: @DKNguyen Makes sense. For the purposes of fiction I just need a believable RPM range. I'm postulating that the two steel flywheels are connected to a titanium gear train which keeps them rotating in opposite directions and electrically in phase when the rotor windings are energized. There's also air turbine elements to drive the two flywheels mounted on a common shaft with them. The assembly is balanced to a fare-thee-well by a college's engineering research department, but there should still be a resonant frequency. Plausibility is more important that accuracy for my purposes.

Comment: A spring and a mass form a resonant system. Structural supports are not infinitely strong, and will have some "springiness". You generally design your structure to be strong enough (weight is usually a driving factor), and deal with the resonance. You may fine tune a resonance so it is not on top of another resonance (they can amplify). Small objects (circuit boards) may resonate in the kilohertz range, Electronic boxes may resonate in the 100s of Hz, and large objects may resonate in the 10s of Hz (your plane example: 2000 RPM/60 sec/min= 33 Hz).

Comment: Your system will have many resonances. The structure holding the flywheels will have resonances and the flywheel itself will have resonances. The flywheel will need to be very strong/stiff to survive, so I am thinking that it's resonance will be high for it's size (100s of Hz?). Resonances only cause issues when they are excited by something (pistons on the plane engine). Your biggest exitations are likely to be whatever is adding/removing energy from the flywheel.

Comment: Again, plausibility is the goal. Could I write it that the engineers found during testing that an objectionable resonance begins at 5400 rpm and they recommend a "never exceed" speed of 5100 rpm?

Comment: Resonances rarely cause instant catestrophic failures. Rather they cause metal to be flexed more than usual and this eventually fatigues metal. Airplanes need to be light, so their design margin is low. I would guess the risk to the airplane itself is the biggest risk (your other question mentioned that this will be carried on a DC-3). The plane wasn't design to carry such a device.

Answer (score 1):

> How is the fundamental frequency of a large rotating body determined?

5000 RPM / 60 = 83.33 Hz is just the fundamental resonance.
Bearing rotation ratios create harmonics per fundamental revolution unless it ia maglev airbearing. In a spacecraft for storing excess energy, they might spin up to 60 kRPM.  This is accentuated by static imbalance and dynamic imbalance that must be offset with calibrated counterweights sensed by an accelerometer just like car wheels. Structural and alias effects will occur as in all spring-mass systems.  **Standing waves occur when there is a discontinuity in impedance coupling waves from one member to another. Its wave frequency is determined by twice the path length and velocity.**  This is true for acoustic and electromagnetic waves and is measured by a reflection coefficient. **The end-stop to a wave, if rigid acts as a short circuit to reflect waves inverted.**

### A recording is necessary with audio+video for any critical analysis. Please advise if possible, and find loudest vibration on the frame.

I don't know of any solid structural frame that does not have resonances unless it has an active overdamped design.

The key factor to minimize damaging effects with sufficiently high resonant frequency is such that the 2nd order pole effects of displacement vs acceleration do not strain the material and the amplification or Q is sufficiently low.

2100 RPM indicates the main structural resonance is around 35 Hz.

### Anecdotal experiences

When I started in Aerospace R&D in '75 every product was tested in-house for shock and vibe. **The best damping material such as Solothane or Lord Mounts still had a Q of 5 even with the lossy or plasticity of an elastomer at the natural resonance with its compliance. **The stiffness must be chosen to dampen the required looseness at the resonant frequency of acceleration**.  I had to find a method to dampen my design of an OCXO that was ultrastable and ruggedized yet subject to drift after resonance during a vibration sweep at 15g excitation for rockets. I was only allotted 5 mm of surrounding space to dampen the vibration. Oddly enough, I ended up using carbon ESD foam used for CMOS to pass my criteria for damping the resonance. The error criteria was frequency stability of 1e-10 or 0.01 part per million used for Doppler ranging.

In control system theory, I learned early that **any 2nd order system with added latency in feedback or time delay or mechanical slack could resonate and require damping to prevent.**  Rotating bearings are commonly resonant and vibration analysis will indicate when maintenance is required. Harmonic effects occur from the primary rotation and gearing effects of a number of balls per revolution with aliasing effects that create difference frequencies.  Harmonics indicated something was wearing- out by being out of round. These are common tests for turbines with 3-axis accelerometers added in critical locations for testing and correlations with acoustic spectrum and repair results.  **Any loose parts tend to resonate with fundamental and harmonic frequencies due to the available displacement and the latency in the structure to support itself from control theory.**

When I was a senior Test Engineer for a disk drive manufacturer, I used 3D Modal Analysis tools with plastic hammer and 3D accelerometer to measure the 3D transfer function and resonances.  The spring-mass structure with rotating and linear motion reveals all the many faults in the structure.  The controlled high actuator had to be resonant-free to avoid overshoot and writing data off-track. The early 5.25" drives all had shock mounts to reduce the spectrum from an impulse or mechanical shock.  The Q and resonances were unavoidable, but it was a tradeoff. As drives got smaller, the precision balance, stiffness of structure and air-bearing effects improved such that adding shock mounts only made it worse, so the solution was to make them as light as possible in the moving parts so they were tight and friction-free in the moving direction and very stiff in the orthogonal directions.  Resonances were always deadly for the servo effects on data errors, with the high-speed noise from ultra-fast seeks so the designs **required the most sophisticated complex electro-mechanical servo solutions (yet appear ultra simple)**, I have ever seen to become error-free with lots of margin.

The best stepper motor solution in the 80's, was from Hitachi-NPL for the first stepper-motor 5.25" hard disk drives. They used a thin plastic rotary disk that contained oil to surround around a brass disk inside to provide the fastest low mass seek speed with damping and a tight stainless steel foil for coupling the motor to moving mass or rails and a digital-controlled acceleration, velocity and position. **I have yet to see any stepper-servo that was faster and so quiet.**  Their quality control system for documentation was state of the art.

### Comments on counter-rotating masses

My primitive understanding is that imperfections in balance result in low-frequency resonances that challenge the natural cancellation of the moments of inertia.  Each flywheel is a structural spring-mass system with resonant frequencies that will sound like a bell when struck. **Any slight differences between the two flywheels will create lower and upper sideband resonances from intermodulation of the airwaves and eddy current frequencies** unless it's in a vacuum on axial magnetic bearings.

> there a way to craft a decent estimate of it given the postulated design parameters?

Design parameters depend on the degrees of freedom in each member, the mass and stress-strain stiffness. The parameters require modeling with test correlation with scale models for accuracy.  The transfer function must be simplified just as it is done with Operation Amplifiers with many transistor stages by adding a capacitor to swamp the phase shift of each stage with a very low-frequency pass filter (10 Hz) and very high gain (10k to 10G).